# How to set-up data to use interaction term in daily time series

Tags: r, interaction

I have a daily time-series of death for all cause and stratified by different disease categories and wanted to find out whether associations between death and pm10 is modified by various disease categories. In the example data, death represents total daily death, cvd those who died due to heart disease and “others” represents all deaths which are not due to heart disease. To model associations between pm10 and various outcomes I use the following scripts.

```
m1<-gam(death ~ pm10 + s(trend)+ s(temp), data=df1, na.action=na.omit, family=poisson)
m2<-gam(cvd ~ pm10 + s(trend)+ s(temp), data=df1, na.action=na.omit, family=poisson)
m3<-gam(others ~ pm10 + s(trend)+ s(temp), data=df1, na.action=na.omit, family=poisson)
```

For each day there total deaths, out of which the majority are due CVD.  On January 1, 1987 there were 130 deaths (65 deaths due to CVD and 65 from other causes).  My aim is it to find out if there is difference in death in CVD group and other causes based on exposure to PM10.  The study question is: Does the death rate in those with CVD and others differ when exposed to PM10.  In stratified analysis I could divide the data into CVD group and other group. But in this task I am interested to run a model in with an interaction term.  But I could not figure out how to do it.
I thought of expanding each row twice and create a dummy variable for both groups(1 for others and 0 for CVD)  and a single column(newdeath)  that  contain two rows for each day to represent death due to others vs. CVD.  With that set up (data set df2 shown below) I wanted to run the following code:

```
minter<-gam(newdeath~ pm10*dummy  + s(trend)+ s(temp), data=df2, na.action=na.omit, family=poisson)
```

However I am not sure whether this data form and model really enables me to achieve what I wanted.

The following code will produce sample data set

```
library(mgcv) 
require(dlnm)
df <- chicagoNMMAPS
df <- chicagoNMMAPS
df1 <- df[,c("date","dow","death","cvd","temp","pm10")] 
df1$trend<-seq(dim(df1)[1]) 
df1$others<-df1$death-df1$cvd # all other non-CVD deaths
```

I have considered the following date set up to solve the problem, but unsure whether it is right.

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(date = structure(c(6209, 6209, 6210, 6210, 6211, 
6211, 6212, 6212, 6213, 6213), class = "Date"), dow = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), class = "factor"), 
    death = c(130L, 130L, 150L, 150L, 101L, 101L, 135L, 135L, 
    126L, 126L), cvd = c(65L, 65L, 73L, 73L, 43L, 43L, 72L, 72L, 
    64L, 64L), temp = c(-0.277777777777778, -0.277777777777778, 
    0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 
    0.555555555555556, -1.66666666666667, -1.66666666666667, 
    0, 0), pm10 = c(26.956073733, 26.956073733, NA, NA, 32.838694951, 
    32.838694951, 39.9560737332, 39.9560737332, NA, NA), trend = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), newdeath = c(65L, 65L, 
    77L, 73L, 58L, 43L, 63L, 72L, 62L, 64L), dummy = c(1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), datalabel = "Written by R.              ", time.stamp = "24 Mar 2015 00:00", .Names = c("date", 
"dow", "death", "cvd", "temp", "pm10", "trend", "newdeath", "dummy"
), formats = c("%dD_m_Y", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
"%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g"), types = c(255L, 253L, 253L, 
253L, 255L, 255L, 253L, 253L, 254L), val.labels = c("", "dow", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", ""), var.labels = c("date", "dow", "death", 
"cvd", "temp", "pm10", "trend", "others", ""), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), version = 12L, label.table = structure(list(
    dow = structure(1:7, .Names = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))), .Names = "dow"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "interaction term for pm10 and deaths with and without heart disease". I originally thought you were just new to mgcv and need a way to get a 2d smooth but after looking some more at the dataset I'm thinking you need statistical consultation. But if you can clearly explain what this "interaction term" is supposed to measure, I will revise my opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow neither. You want to model interaction between pm10 and what exactly?

Comment: @BondedDust and dominic, sorry that my request was not clear. I have edited the post with more detail.

Comment: You will need to determine the proper treatment for the NA's in PM10. Most regression functions will do casewise deletion for them. You also need to clarify whether "cvd" is a cvd-death or is a marker of cardiovascular disease. Your problem description seems to conflate those tow possibilities.

Comment: @BondedDust CVD is number of deaths per day due to cardiovascular disease.

Comment: That's what I thought and why I asked the first part of that two-part question. I consider both parts unanswered. Re part 2: We have this question "Does the death rate in those with CVD..." but we have no way of knowing who "those with CVD" might be.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @BondedDust... it seems your data is already too much aggregated to answer your question, moreover with the tools you intend. What you could measure however is the relation between pm10 and the proportion of deaths due to heart conditions:

```
df1$prop.cvd <- df1$cvd / df1$death
```

And then visualize

```
plot(prop.cvd ~ pm10, data = df1)
```

And maybe use this variable as a response variable in a regression model, like so -- but then the question asked is different than yours and doesn't take into account any latency in the effect of pm10 and time. For that you'd need other tools but I'm in no position to help you here. Maybe asking the question on Cross-Validated could help you move further.

```
model <- glm(prop.cvd ~ pm10 + temp, data = df1)
summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = prop.cvd ~ pm10 + temp, data = df1)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.1632  -0.0351  -0.0014   0.0349   0.3323  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.435e-01  1.529e-03 290.051   <2e-16 ***
pm10         5.294e-05  4.161e-05   1.272    0.203    
temp        -6.436e-04  7.437e-05  -8.654   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.002732995)

    Null deviance: 13.498  on 4862  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 13.282  on 4860  degrees of freedom
  (251 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: -14898

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```